# android remove view from alertdialog

Tags: android, view, android-alertdialog

Hi i have a MainActivity class where i have a listview populated by rss items. When i click on item list my app shows me an alertdialog where i can see in message box the item details. My problem is that after i show alertdialog when i close it and open a new item my app crashes giving me this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Here my java class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        wv = new WebView(this);

        try {
            url = new URL("http://www.unikore.it/index.php/ingegneria-informatica-home?format=feed");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new ReadRssTask().execute(url);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
                OptionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                OptionDialog.setTitle(listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                s = rssItems.get(position).getDescription();
                if(s.contains("href=")){
                    s.substring(0,s.indexOf("</div>"));
                    wv.loadData(s, "text/html", "UTF-8");
                    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                            view.loadUrl(url);
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    OptionDialog.setView(wv);
                }else {
                    OptionDialog.setMessage(s.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", ""));
                }
                OptionDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

i tried using `OptionDialog.dismiss()` method but app crashes anyway.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the instantiation of the `WebView` just before accessing the object.

```
s = rssItems.get(position).getDescription();
if(s.contains("href=")){ 
  wv = new WebView(this);
  wv.loadData(s, "text/html", "UTF-8");
  // other code
```